# Python Flask paginate formulation

Tags: html, flask

I'm learning Flask Web Development book , and in Chapter 13 , it's about "comments for the blog post"

The route function of post is as below , the book said "when page = -1" , it will caculate how much comments totally , and to be divided "FLASKY_COMMENTS_PER_PAGE" , then it can know how many pages totally and decided which is the last page that you will go to.

> - But what confused me is that why the "(post.comments.count()" need to subtract 1 ???

i.e. If the comments quantity is 22 , then I added 1 comment
The caculation should be (23-1)//FLASKY_COMMENTS_PER_PAGE + 1 ???

I really don't know why I should subtract 1....

```
@main.route('/post/<int:id>')
def post(id):
    post = Post.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = CommentForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        comment = Comment(body = form.body.data, post = post, author = current_user._get_current_object())
        db.session.add(comment)
        flash('Your comment has been published.')
        return redirect(url_for('.post',id = post.id, page = -1))
    page = request.args.get('page',1,type=int)
    if page == -1:
        page = (post.comments.count()-1)//current_app.config['FLASKY_COMMENTS_PER_PAGE']+1
        pagination = post.comments.order_by(Comment.timestamp.asc()).paginate(
            page,per_page = current_app.config['FLASKY_COMMENTS_PER_PAGE'],
            error_out = False)
        comments = pagination.items
    return render_template('post.html',posts=[post],form = form,comments=comments,pagination = pagination)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see this line:

```
page = (post.comments.count()-1)//current_app.config['FLASKY_COMMENTS_PER_PAGE']+1
```

let `FLASKY_COMMENTS_PER_PAGE` be 10. The page numbering starts from 1. Without the subtracting when there are 9 comments: `9//10 + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1` which is still good, but when you got 10 comments: `10//10 + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2`. So you got 2 pages instead of 1. That's why you need to subtract 1 from the total comments.

Comment: ah....I got it...it avoid the mistake when comments quantities are times of per page setting....thanks a lot...haha have a nice weekend